# Bash Script to gather directory and server info on a single line

Tags: bash, scripting, directory, ls, hostname

I am currently using the below command in a ,sh to gather a list of contents of a specific folder, on a list of servers, depicted by list.txt (contains IPs)

```
for f in `cat serverlist.txt`; do
    echo "### $f ###";
    sshpass -p PASSWORD ssh USER@$f ls /usr/local/folder  >>list.txt;
done
```

Whilst this works, its only half of my problem, I am a total novice with BASH

What I am trying to obtain is a list formatted as such

```
file1.HOSTNAMEOFSERVER1
file2.HOSTNAMEOFSERVER1
file3.HOSTNAMEOFSERVER1
file1.HOSTNAMEOFNEXTSERVER2
file2.HOSTNAMEOFNEXTSERVER2
file3.HOSTNAMEOFNEXTSERVER2
file1.HOSTNAMEOFNEXTSERVER3
```

Is any one able to help?

Comment: What does the script currently output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Untested:

```
while read host; do
    sshpass -p PASSWORD ssh USER@"$host" ls /usr/local/folder | 
        sed 's/$/.'"$host"/;
done < serverlist.txt
```

DO NOT ACTUALLY PUT YOUR PASSWORD in a script like this.  Set up your ssh keys instead.

Comment: This adds the host name, but perhaps in combination with mikael's answer it will be formatted into columns.. I think you both answered a part of the question

Comment: When the output of `ls` is not a tty (as it is (not) when piped to sed), the output is in one column anyway, and the -C1 is redundant.

Answer (score 0):

Just format the `ls` output into columns with the option `-C1`: `ls -C1 /usr/local/folder`.

Comment: This command line option will format the ls output into columns, I see mikael did not add an explanation, my edit is pending

Comment: I have added some explanation. Thanks.